# ant check internet connection

Tags: deployment, ant, build, connection

Is there a way to check in ant if an internet connection is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html to get this information using an external command.

[Check internet connection in bash](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2009/04/02/tiny-bash-scripts-check-internet-connection-availability/) (you could write a small app for this) or try to ping some site and write the result somewhere.

[Handle Exec task output in Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070643/ant-script-handling-return-value-from-exec)

Comment: Thanks, Can you tell me a command in linux that could do this. and how to get the output of the command and set it to a property

Comment: @muthiahmerchant That answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929368/how-to-test-a-internet-connection-in-bash